# Activate waypoint on top and bottom of div - jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-waypoints

I'm trying to activate a waypoint when the user scrolls in from the top and the bottom of the same div. This then changes the active state on a navigation element. I know the default is top of the div but how do I do both?

```
$('#1').waypoint(function() {

   $(".desktop-menu ul li").children().removeClass("active"); $(".desktop-menu ul li ul li").children().removeClass("active");

   $("#chapt-1").addClass("active");

}, { offset: 0 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Append an element with `id="#1-bottom"` right after the `id="#1"` element and declare a waypoint on it too.

Then, scrolling from top to bottom will trig the `#1 waypoint` first and scrolling from bottom to top will trig the `#1-bottom waypoint` first.

HTML

```
<div id="#1">[...]</div>
<div id="#1-bottom"></div>
```

jQuery

```
$('#1').waypoint(function () { [top to bottom logic] });
$('#1-bottom').waypoint(function () { [bottom to top logic] });
```